# will chia coins mining HDD be reusable?

Tags: hard-disk

I am expecting Chia coin price to crash soon and people will have to sell off all their HDD in second hand market to recover some value. May I know if Chia is an intense R/W mining application? I heard there is a time limit thing they only allow changing some hash after at least a certain amount of time. Say when the Chia gold rush ends in 2 ~ 6 months, will the HDDs be at end of life cycle? or they will still have a lot of MTBF being a worthy buy? I am not looking for definite answers, I want some educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't buy SSD 2nd hand. After Chia there will be another file coin, just like it happened with all the CPU then GPU mining coins.
I would expect people to sell SSD cheap right before they die. So no 2nd hand SSDs.
HDD are mostly used as storage in file coins mining, the SSDs are the intense use victims in this story.